# What term means "comprehension of one's own words"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Comprehension typically refers to one's ability to understand another's words, whether heard or read.

There may be some contexts, such as in a school, where students say things without really knowing the meaning. Comprehension may refer to this as well, but I need something more specific and professional that will be understood to mean "understanding one's own words".

What is a term that specifically refers to one's ability to understand what they themselves are saying?

Comment: Neither *comprehend* not *understand* have the "another's" tag. Have you checked a dictionary? Also, the words mean the same, so, if *understand* can apply to oneself, then technically, so can *comprehend*.

Comment: @Kris Ah, the _there's a strong possibility that synonymity here is broad enough for the words to be interchangeable in this usage_ 'technically'.

Comment: Huh, @EdwinAshworth Aint so?

Comment: Btw, *nor* not *not* -- typo.

Comment: I think the problem is not understanding one's own words, rather than understanding them....Also, what do you mean by comprehension, anyway? It is not usually applied to oneself. I think here you really mean: realize what they are actually saying.

Answer (score -1):

An idiomatic expression for this is **to have a full / good *command* of the language**.

> **command** [n] ...
> 2 ... d: facility in use
>
> *a good command of French*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/command)]

> Van Eyck did not have full command of either classical Greek or Latin,
> and made errors, so readings by modern scholars are divided.

[[ludwig.guru_have a full command of](https://ludwig.guru/s/have+a+full+command+of)]

If knowledge of the subject matter is being focused on,

**"She knows what she's talking about / her stuff / her onions"**

are idiomatic expressions, decreasing in formality. *She has a good command of her subject* is again available if formality is required.

Comment: Having a good command of the language certainly includes what the OP calls comprehension of one's own words, but it seems much broader than that.

Comment: Yes; it's a hypernym. Though 'comprehension' in language _is_, as OP says, orientated towards being able to decipher another's meaning.

Answer (score -1):

"Autofluency", though not an existing word, seems most appropriate for this role, don't you think?

Comment: "Non-existing 'words' " are off-topic on ELU.